# issue with starting perceptilabs

Tags: python, installation, artificial-intelligence

I made a python 3.7 environment in conda and downloaded perceptilabs using pip but when I write perceptilabs in the CMD it gives me this error:

screenshot of the issue:
[image]

I haven't tried anything yet to fix it because i don't understand what's wrong